# wkhtmltopdf outputs garbled text

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I just installed the latest static build of [wkhtmltopdf-amd64](https://github.com/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/) (0.12.3).  On any html page I convert to PDF, the text appears as solid squares.

Example of google's homepage as PDF:

```
[acoder@box bin]# ./wkhtmltopdf-amd64 http://google.com goog.pdf
```

[image]

Or, here's an even simpler HTML source doc:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
</head>
<body>

<p>Hello world.
<table><tr><td>I am a table</td></tr></table>
<pre>formatted</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a missing dependency, `urw-fonts`.  After that was installed, converted text is readable.

**For clarity & documentation on a minimal install of EL7:**

1. Grab the [wkhtmltopdf-amd](https://github.com/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/archive/master.zip) binary and unpack to a temporary location.
2. Install dependencies: `yum install libXrender libXext fontconfig urw-fonts`
3. Test the binary with `wkhtmltopdf-amd -V` - this should print the version (0.12.3 as of today).
4. Next test that it converts documents as expected.  `wkhtmltopdf-amd http://google.com googlehomepage.pdf`

If the output PDF looks good, then copy the binary to `/usr/bin` and call it done.